# How to adjust Mongo Aggregation Query $group to place matching key in an object rather than having two items in a $group

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an **aggregation query** that is producing results in a mostly desired way except I need to **only group by branchId** ( not branchId and name ) **and place the "name" values in an object** with their relevant results.

SCHEMA:

```
  {
    process: { type: String, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    error: { type: String },
    action: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      enum: ['started', 'stopped', 'processing', 'completed', 'errored']
    },
    location: {
      branchId: { type: String }
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
```

This is the current aggregation query:

```
[
    {
        $match: {
            createdAt: { $gte: ISODate("2020-06-24T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            $lte: ISODate("2020-06-25T00:00:00.000+0000") 
          }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { branchId: '$location.branchId', name: '$name' },
            started: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$action', 'started'] }, 1, 0] } },
            processing: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$action', 'processing'] }, 1, 0] } },
            errored: {  $sum: {  $cond: [{ $eq: ['$action', 'errored'] }, 1, 0] } },
            completed: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$action', 'completed'] }, 1, 0] }
            }
        }
    },
]
```

CURRENT RESPONSE:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "branchId" : "1", 
        "name" : "Product 1"
    }, 
    "started" : 1.0, 
    "processing" : 1.0, 
    "errored" : 0.0, 
    "completed" : 0.0
},
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "branchId" : "1", 
        "name" : "Product 2"
    }, 
    "started" : 1.0, 
    "processing" : 1.0, 
    "errored" : 1.0, 
    "completed" : 1.0
}
```

How would I modify the query to produce something similar to the following **DESIRED RESPONSE:** ?

```
{ 
    "_id" : "1",
    "product_1": {
        "started" : true,  // although 1.0 and 0.0 is acceptable
        "processing" : true, 
        "errored" : true, 
        "completed" : false
    },
    "product_2": {
        "started" : true, 
        "processing" : true, 
        "errored": false, 
        "completed" : true
    }
},
```

I created this playground to assist in testing: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zDaxC-SYtN4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use the [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) operator to create an object based on the value of the document.

```
{k:"hello", v:"world"}  --> {"hello":"world"}
```

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$location.branchId",
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $arrayToObject: [
        {
          $concatArrays: [
            [
              { "k": "_id", "v": "$_id" }
            ],
            {
              $map: {
                input: "$data",
                in: {
                  k: "$$this.name",
                  v: {
                    started: { $eq: ["$$this.action","started"},
                    processing: { $eq: ["$$this.action","processing"]},
                    errored: { $eq: ["$$this.action","errored"]},
                    completed: {$eq: ["$$this.action","completed"]}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m7cT4kHXmMO) |[Alternative 3.4](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h8PagEXPIjo)

Comment: Valijon - Looks like I need to upgrade to Mongo 4.2. But yes, this is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewTaylor I've added alternative with the `$replaceRoot` operator instead of `$replaceWith`